# Hide button in Swift 3

Tags: xcode, button, swift3, hide

I've just started with coding and I really want to know how to hide buttons.

What I want to do is when I press my button:

**Start:** I want to let the start button and the back button disappear.

It's done with Outlets and Actions.

I already searched a bit but when I wanted to do it, it said that the `do` keyword is expected to designate a block of statements.

I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 20):

Once you have your outlets connected, simply change the `isHidden` property to true.

```
IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton
IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton

IBAction func tapStart(sender: AnyObject?){
   self.startButton.isHidden = true
   self.backButton.isHidden = true
}
```